# PDF to Text in Python

Tags: python, pdf

I'm converting PDFs in Python with this code:

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from cStringIO import StringIO

def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    fp = file(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
       interpreter.process_page(page)

    text = retstr.getvalue()

    fp.close()
    device.close()
    retstr.close()
    return text

try:
    output = convert_pdf_to_txt("AI - A method for registration of 3-D shapes.pdf")
    print(type(output))
    outputFile = open("consultaSalida.txt","w")
    outputText = "".join(str(output).encode("utf-8").splitlines())
except Exception:
    print("Archivo con problemas")

outputFile.write(outputText)
```

This works perfect with some PDFs, but with some papers, I obtain the following output:

```
Å­y­y¸Â¼¾½P¦¨ÎSÎk§g±§Sªm²©·¡«ªPÅªm« ¹g«µ¬®­y­y«µ¶S¶S¯gºÐ·¥°=±©B·¨²³²Ãªm­y«½P´}¼¾»U±K·¥Îg¸m±³©µ«µ´}±¶SÏN­yºR©µ« §gª®¹ÐÎSªP«µ·¥­yÇ¸Ó¿¶U·¥·¥»S¼¾¸=±¹¨±³¸mªm±Â±·¥¸Ã©µË%ºyÖR­y¸P×®«µ¶«½)ªm»SªPªm»S¼¾»g±u«µ½f½Ê¶N¿§SÎU»S¼Â·¥«µÎ¤²m¯¤±»À±Ã¸^¸)ÒT§S­¥½P¿±_Å±r­y¶S¯g½m­y§S°=¶g±ºy¬®²ºyÁSªP±­y« ½=´}¼¾ª¾±½K«µ·¨¶S·¥·¡¶S¶Sªm­y±ÁR¶gÁÀ¬ØÌ"ÁS½P­y­y«µ¸P¼¾½)ªP«µªm«µ¶S¶U»gºI·¡±XªP·¥±ÃÎ¤¶gÁ6­yÁÀÎS½P§g½m­y»S©Ñ¸P·¡·¥ªPªm«µ¸m«µ¶S«µ­y¶SºR¶RºÂ¯U½P»U·¥«µ·ÃÄÃ½P´}±^±ÃÈÓ±uÁ6Ò¯¤Ç¼Â«µ±±Ã§SÈ)¶{© ¶SªP«¼r­y¬®¶N­y·¥¬®¯g«µ±°=¶S©µ±«© ªm²¹¾«µªP½P«²¼Ô´}¸m±¾« ªP·¥«µ±³²ÎS´}«µÎgÄ­y±Ã¸m©µ§g­}ÁwªP·¥«µÅÆ²Ó­y­
```

Do you know what is the problem?
Thank you!!1

Comment: Probably a unicode problem. I see that the output file has a spanish name. Perhaps do you only come across this error when dealing with documents with spanish specific characters?

Comment: But the PDF file is in english :/

Comment: It is, alas, still a common misconception to think that you *always* can extract *all* text out of *every* possible PDF. Can you correctly copy this text out of a PDF using Acrobat Reader? Can you post a link to a PDF that exhibits this symptom?

Comment: Hi! this is the PDF http://eecs.vanderbilt.edu/courses/CS359/other_links/papers/1992_besl_mckay_ICP.pdf

Comment: Your test PDF is a scanned article and does not contain any plain text. It's somewhat surprising you get *anything* – is pdfminer known to use some kind of OCR?

Answer (score 0):

You can use google's [Tesseract-OCR](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) and the documentation can be found [here](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/). It's free and works perfectly. There is a python library and is called
[pytesseract](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/).

Answer (score 0):

The first test of any PDF for extraction should be "Can I copy the text to a Word Processor", If you get copy restricted then test using READ ALOUD  if so then it is equally game for extraction.

[image]

If you get gibberish or gobbledygook, then it is likely it was previously OCRed or set with a bad font definition and that will need replacing.

If all you get is copy image then it is fair to say it is most likely simply a scanned document and also requires OCR before or as part of text extraction. However beware a two column "Article" like above will often combine the two top lines as one long line, and in avove example the staggers between left and right columns will make that an even bigger problem.

By far the easiest is to use a GUI character replacement because you can spell check or adjust the inevitable mistaken characters. If you need to do that as a bulk exercise then it is worth training an OCR engine like Tesseract or similar but commercial text recognition offerings should fare much better that that simple method.

The next question is how to extract text from such a PDF using a program and the simplest is export the text as PDFtoText:- (every Python installation should include the needed simple utilities) Here I am on 32bit without any need for Python, so using the traditional Xpdf version. Note how -layout is keeping the original left and right sequences, but that is not good for sequential text parsing, thus often a problem when using OCR.

[image]

However using the command line we can ask that the righthand column be placed in raw terms after the left hand column, but may have to experiment with the clipping marginb value to remove any unwanted footing between the two blocks.

[image]

***The eagle-eyed amongst you may have spotted the really bad OCR FAILURE (hint the 72 is certainly not correct)***